# Jython fails to load Scikit Module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jython

I'm trying to use Jython to fetch predictions from a Scikit model. But Jyton is failing to import the scikit module with an odd AttributeError.

Here's the Java exception:

```
Exception in thread "MainThread" Traceback (most recent call last):  
 File "C:/pydata/loadModel.py", line 1, in <module>
     from sklearn.externals import joblib   File "C:\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py",
 line 98, in <module>
    warnings.filterwarnings('always', category=DeprecationWarning, 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

This is how I'm loading the modules in Java

```
        PythonInterpreter intep = new PythonInterpreter();

        PySystemState sys = intep.getSystemState();            
        sys.path.append(new PyString("C:\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\site-packages"));

        intep.execfile("C:/pydata/loadModel.py");
```

I'm on Java8 with Python 3.6.3 and Jython-Standalone 2.5.2

Thanks

Comment: Scikit-learn is built on NumPy and SciPy, which do not work with Jython. See https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/faq.html#does-numpy-scipy-work-with-jython.

Comment: The AttributeError in the question stems from the fact that the `format()` string method was added in Python 2.6 while you use Jython 2.5. Upgrading to Jython 2.7 won't help. You will just get other errors.

Comment: But keep an eye on JyNI: http://jyni.org/